# How to put other layouts below gridlayout?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have a gridlayout that takes the full width of my screen but only about 3/4 of the height of my screen. I've just declared it in the xml as follows:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chessBoard"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="8"
    tools:context=".GridLayoutActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell00"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_castle"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="00" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell01"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_knight"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="01" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell02"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_mage"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="02" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell03"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_queen"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="03" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell04"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_king"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="04" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell05"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_mage"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="05" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell06"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_knight"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="06" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell07"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_castle"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="07" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell10"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_soldier"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="10" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell11"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_soldier"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="11" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell12"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_soldier"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="12" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell13"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_soldier"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="13" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell14"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_soldier"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="14" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell15"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_soldier"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="15" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell16"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_soldier"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="16" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell17"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/black_soldier"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="17" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell20"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="20" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell21"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="21" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell22"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"      
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="22" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell23"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="23" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell24"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"     
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="24" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell25"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="25" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell26"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="26" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell27"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="27" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell30"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="30" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell31"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="31" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell32"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"      
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="32" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell33"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="33" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell34"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"     
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="34" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell35"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="35" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell36"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="36" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell37"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="37" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell40"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="40" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell41"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="41" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell42"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"      
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="42" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell43"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="43" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell44"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"     
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="44" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell45"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="45" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell46"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="46" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell47"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="47" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell50"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="50" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell51"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="51" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell52"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"      
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="52" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell53"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="53" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell54"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"     
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="54" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell55"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"        
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="55" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell56"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="56" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell57"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="57" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell60"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/udyr_facing_right"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="60" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell61"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/udyr_facing_right"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="61" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell62"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/udyr_facing_right"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="62" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell63"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/udyr_facing_right"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="63" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell64"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/udyr_facing_left"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="64" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell65"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/udyr_facing_left"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="65" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell66"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/udyr_facing_left"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="66" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell67"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/udyr_facing_left"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="67" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell70"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/trundle_facing_right"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="70" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell71"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/sejuani_facing_right"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="71" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell72"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/lissandra_facing_right"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="72" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell73"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/queen_ashe"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="73" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell74"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/king_trynd"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="74" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell75"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/lissandra_facing_left"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="75" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell76"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/sejuani_facing_left"
        android:background="@color/chessBrown"
        android:contentDescription="76" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell77"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/trundle_facing_left"
        android:background="@color/chessTan"
        android:contentDescription="77" />

</GridLayout>
```

How can I put another layout below this gridlayout?

Comment: What is the parent layout and what have you tried?

Comment: @codeMagic I updated my exact gridlayout. The parent layout is just the gridlayout\

Comment: I don't use `GridLayout` but if you want to put something below it then there needs to be a separate parent layout or else there is nothing to put another layout below

Comment: @codeMagic post your comment as an answer and i'll accept it because I got it working, thanks.

Comment: I have posted an answer with one possible example. Feel free to edit if there's something you think helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one root `layout` to contain your `GridView` **and** the `layout` that you want *below* the `GridLayout`. If `GridlLayout` is the root `layout` then there can't be anything below it. It can be `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc... But something needs to contain the `GridLayout` and the `layout`/`View` below the `GridLayout`. Ex

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/chessBoard"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="8"
       tools:context=".GridLayoutActivity" >

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/cell00"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_row="0"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:src="@drawable/black_castle"
         android:background="@color/chessTan"
         android:contentDescription="00" />

    <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/cell01"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:layout_column="1"
         android:layout_row="0"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:src="@drawable/black_knight"
         android:background="@color/chessBrown"
         android:contentDescription="01" />
     ...
  </GridLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="chessBoard"  // will place it below the GridLayout
  >
     //some views inside LinearLayout
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```